# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Support for environments other than Mobile ones?

Tags: facebook, windows-7, ibm-mobilefirst, igoogle

After reading the IBM Worklight 6.0 documentation, I would like to know why iGoogle, Mac OS X Dashboard, Windows 7 / Vista Gadgets and Facebook environments were removed in this latest version.

Is there alternative provided for these environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `iGoogle` is discontinued by **Google**
- `OS X Dashboard` and `Vista Gadgets` marketshare is likely slim to none with no demand for it
- `Facebook` can still be used via the `Desktop Browser` web page environment (there is also a [migration guide](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/t_manually_migrating_Facebook_apps.html))

I assume the move must also have some strategic value for IBM/Worklight; this is not the place for analysis questions, but for technical questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply